# Photon thought experiment

Tags: photons, thought-experiment

If I have a closed box of length 299,792,458 metres fitted with mirrors on opposite sides inside the box that are reflecting light vertically (up down) again and again, then what will happen if I move the box to my right while the photon is halfway between the mirrors? Will the photon move with the box? If so, then how? The photon takes one second to travel from one mirror to another. What will happen if i move the box in the direction which light is going as in the diagram. Will the photon never reach the top mirror?[image: Closed box with mirrors]

Comment: The box need not be long. A laser is such a box, with one of the mirrors partially transparent.

Comment: Actually what i asked is that photon reflects vertically -up down not right left

Comment: Short answer: no, the photon will not move with the box when you move the box sideways.  The photon will hit one of the side walls and (presumably) be absorbed.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about accelerating frames in relativity.

Comment: And what will happen if i move the box vertically upwards at the speed of light while the photon is moving upwards like in the diagram. Will the photon never reach the top mirror?

Comment: @Hark if you move the box upward, then what will happen is pretty much just Ander said in his answer, but if you move the box to the right suddenly, then I don't know.

Comment: Ander said in case where photon bounces left and right but i'm asking about vertical movement of photon

Comment: 'Up'/'down' and 'left'/'right' are directions that make sense in the context of a picture and can change meaning if someone else draws their image differently than you drew yours. The key seems to be that you want the motion of the box to be 'perpendicular' (or 'transverse') to the direction of the initial photon motion. The new image doesn't really address this confusion because it doen't show the intended direction of motion *of the box*.

Comment: What will happen if i move the box the speed of light in the same direction as photon is going in the diagram. Will the photon reach the top mirror?

Answer (score 15):

[image: Spacetime diagram of photon bouncing in a moved box.]

The easiest way of seeing what happens is to draw a space-time diagram. The stationary box walls form two vertical parallel lines with a 45 degree zigzag path for the photon as it bounces between them.

When you move the box the photon will not change speed - relativity tells us that light always move at lightspeed no matter what inertial coordinate system you use. The result is just that the approach to one side gets delayed (as seen by us who are not moving with the box) since the wall is receding as the photon tries to catch up, and the approach to the other side speeded up since the wall is approaching while the photon moves towards it. Overall there will be fewer bounces as the box is moving: we would say there has been a time dilation for the box.

Comment: I understood the question as moving the box orthogonally to the photon's way, not parallel.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann that is correct, and is what the diagram shows. It’s a space time diagram.

Comment: Why then do we maintain the constancy of the speed of light, since in the above diagram it is clearly taking longer to traverse the *relative* distance between the two walls (hence why each cycle takes longer)?

Comment: @Steve The drawing here shows only the axes for the initial frame of reference. You have to add [the *tilted* axes of the frame that agrees with the intermediate motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_diagram) to evaluate how long the traversal takes in that frame. It will turn out to take the same amount of time both ways while the box coasts.

Comment: @dmckee, but all the tilted axes do is demonstrate that the very definition of the speed of light is being changed - that is, it's numerical constancy is being maintained by redefining the scales of time and distance on which it rests, so that the same *relation* between the scales is maintained but the absolute values which underpin those scales are indeed changed (I.e. the light is given more time to travel between each side of the box, whether we conceive it as travelling extra distance at the same speed, or the same distance at a reduced speed, but the relation is maintained).

Comment: @Steve The fact that it violates your intuition doesn't make it wrong and experimental data agrees with all the prediction made under that assumption. Empirical results trump intuition.

Comment: I also think this doesn't answer the question as asked. The box is moving perpendicular to the light, so the light will end up colliding with a transverse side -- a long one without a mirror. It won't continue bouncing back and forth as shown in this diagram.

Comment: @Tim:  If PauloEbermann is correct, then the diagram can't be correct, becaus Paulo's interpretation requires two spatial dimensions, and the diagram shows only one.

Comment: @dmckee, I'm not arguing that relativity itself violates intuition. I'm saying that the "tilting of axes" translates to the underlying scales of measurement being adjusted to maintain a fixed numerical relation between time and distance - therefore, the speed of light is numerically constant because the units in which it is measured are being jigged to *keep* it numerically constant. Am I empirically wrong?

Comment: @Steve You are mathematically wrong. The "tilting of axes" is *not* equivalent to changing the units of measurement. A simple analogy: say you have a 10-meter vertical flagpole. Someone who leans to one side at 30° (i.e. their axes are tilted) measures it and finds the top is only 8.66 meters above its bottom. This is *not* equivalent to them using different "meter" units. (It's not fully equivalent to the relativistic case either, but only because rotations in Minkowski space are different from Euclidean space.)

Comment: This answer misinterpret the question. In the diagram of this answer, during t = 0 to 3 s, the box is at rest. *But* the question does say when the box is at rest the photon just hit the mirrors at the ceiling and the floor (no hitting on the left or right wells)

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it *is* equivalent to changing the unit when the unit in the first place is *defined as* the distance to the top of the pole. We would then say the height of the pole is numerically constant. There is nothing mathematically incorrect about it.